# I can't connect to the service when I call bindService

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm studying service . I've been having trouble calling bindService.

I can initialize it with the startforegradService() method, but when I connect to the service the connection does not happen

here is the activity code

```
package com.example.soccer

import android.Manifest
import android.app.Service
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.ServiceConnection
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.IBinder
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.collectAsState
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.soccer.ui.theme.SoccerTheme
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.example.soccer.servics.Servic

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    lateinit var sev: Servic
    var sevicoIniciado:Boolean =false
    var conStat:Boolean =false
    val con = object:ServiceConnection {
        override fun onServiceConnected(p0: ComponentName?, p1: IBinder?) {
Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"coexao iiciada",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            val bind = p1 as Servic.MBinder
            sev = bind.getS()
            conStat = true
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"coexao iiciada",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        override fun onServiceDisconnected(p0: ComponentName?) {
            conStat=false
        }

        override fun onBindingDied(name: ComponentName?) {

            super.onBindingDied(name)
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"acesso bloqueado",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        override fun onNullBinding(name: ComponentName?) {

            super.onNullBinding(name)
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"nulll",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        
    }
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

      val a=  Intent()
        a.component= ComponentName("com.example.soccer","com.example.soccer.servics.Servic")
        a.also {
            bindService(it,con,Context.BIND_IMPORTANT)

        }

    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()

    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if(sevicoIniciado==false) {Intent(this,Servic::class.java).also { startForegroundService(it) }
            sevicoIniciado=true}



      /*  */


        setContent {
            SoccerTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    
                     Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,modifier=Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                        Greeting("Android")

                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(40.dp))

                        if(!conStat){
                            valores(string = "nao conectado")


                        }else {
                            if(::sev.isInitialized){
                              var a = sev.contagem().collectAsState(initial = "")

                                valores( string = a.value)
                            }
                            else valores(string = "nao inicializado")

                        }

                         Button(onClick = {
                             this@MainActivity.bindService(Intent(this@MainActivity,Servic::class.java),con,0)
                         }) {

                         }
                    }




                }
            }
        }
    }

}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",

    )
}
@Composable
fun valores(string:String){
    Text(text = string)
}
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    SoccerTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```

here is the service code

```
package com.example.soccer.servics

import android.Manifest
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Notification
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Binder
import android.os.Build
import android.os.IBinder
import android.os.IInterface
import android.os.Parcel
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat
import java.io.FileDescriptor
import com.example.soccer.R
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flow
import java.nio.channels.Channel

class Servic :Service(){
    val mb = MBinder()
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun notificacao(): Notification {


            val name="aprendendo sobre sevicos"
            val desc= "aprendendo sobre services"
            val imp=NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH

            val can =NotificationChannel("soccer",name,imp).apply { description=desc }
            val not:NotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            not.createNotificationChannel(can)


        val bui: Notification = Notification.Builder(this,"soccer")
           .setSmallIcon(androidx.core.R.drawable.notification_bg)
            .setContentText("servico iniciado")
            .setContentTitle("serviço")
            .build()

return bui
    }
 fun contagem():Flow<String> = flow {

     var l:Long =0

     while (true){

         l++

        emit( l.toString())


     }


 }
    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return mb
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

        startForeground(10,notificacao())
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"servico iniciado",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        return START_STICKY
    }

    inner class MBinder:Binder(){
       fun getS():Servic = this@Servic
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"servico morto",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

here is the manifest code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Soccer"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Soccer">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.example.soccer.servics.Servic"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
            android:description="@string/app_name"
            android:visibleToInstantApps="true"

            >

        </service>

    </application>
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.example.soccer.servics.Servic"/>
</queries>
</manifest>
```

I already looked for some solutions on the site itself, and unfortunately I didn't find it.

I notice the ServiceConnection object's method is not called